# Kafka concurrency setting on listener to limit parallel processing

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, concurrency

I'm not really 100% sure if I understand Kafka concurrency setting correctly, so hopefully a simple question:

Let's assume I have a typical Spring Boot application and in it a KafkaListener consuming a topic that has multiple (many) partitions.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ["#{appProperties.topic}"], concurrency = "1")
fun receiveMessages(record: ConsumerRecord<Key, Value?>) {
```

And let's say I set the `concurrency` parameter to 1. My question is, does this **ensure** that the messages are being consumed by one listener only, in a single thread, even if I deploy multiple instances of the Spring Boot application to work in parallel (Kubernetes)? Is this concurrency parameter set on Kafka itself, as opposed to the application? Will it prevent new instances of the application from reading anything from the topic if there is already one reading from it?

I'm assuming all the listeners have the same group id/belong to the same consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

the parameter concurrency is limited to the single SpringApplication, so if you have multiple replicas of a service on Kubernetes, you will have more consumers for the same Kafka topic.

For example, settings this:

```
concurrency = 1
```

Let's consider a scenario with a topic, `Topic1`, having 6 partitions. With 1 replica, all partitions will be assigned to a single consumer of that replica. If you add a new replica, Kafka Brokers will perform rebalancing, typically distributing partitions equally between the two consumers. In our example, you would have 3 partitions assigned to replica 1 and 3 partitions assigned to replica 2.

The `concurrency` parameter will affect every single replica. In the previous example, you can avoid adding a new replica by setting `concurrency` to 2. Spring will then instantiate 2 threads as consumers on each replica. However, be mindful that this will impact the memory of every single replica because you will have multiple consumers on the same replica.

Note: Consumers with the same group ID will not read the same messages, but will operate in parallel if more than 1 partition is provided.

Hope this will help to understand more on concurrency parameter :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. So if I want to prevent parallel processing of a topic that has multiple partitions, is there any way to do that? Or do I need to stream the content of that topic to another topic with only 1 partition and read from that?

Comment: If you don't want parallel processing you must have only 1 partition yes or only 1 consumer and only 1 replica on cluster K8S. But note that more replicas will be useless because you will have new consumers that will stay stucked. They will only produces CPU overload on brokers.